# Cast Hibernate result to a list of objects

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate call in my DAO that looks like this

```
List<Associate> associate = (List<Associate>)session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM associates WHERE fk_id = :id AND fk_associate_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE fk_user_type = 2)").setParameter("id", id).list();
```

I am getting an error saying that I cannot cast the resulting list to the model type Associate. I don't understand why this is happening. I am returning only the fields that are in the associates table.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to specify the class of entity the result should be converted to using `addEntity()`, because you are executing SQL query that doesn't know anything about entities:

```
List<Associate> associate = (List<Associate>) session.createSQLQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM associates WHERE fk_id = :id AND fk_associate_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE fk_user_type = 2)")
    .addEntity(Associate.class)
    .setParameter("id", id).list();
```

**See also:**

- [18.1.2. Entity queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e17313)

Comment: is there any way to use a DTO class instead of Entity class here ?

Comment: @Vlad   Does adding .addEntity(Associate.class) affects any performance?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to apply a **ResultTransformer** to native SQL queries, allowing it to return non-managed entities.

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT NAME, BIRTHDATE FROM CATS")
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CatDTO.class))
```

The above query will return a list of CatDTO which has been instantiated and injected the values of NAME and BIRTHNAME into its corresponding properties or fields.

source : [Link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e17636)