# What is the "proper" way to cast Hibernate Query.list() to List<Type>?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I'm a newbie with Hibernate, and I'm writing a simple method to return a list of objects
matching a specific filter. `List<Foo>` seemed a natural return type.

Whatever I do, I can't seem to make the compiler happy, unless I employ an ugly `@SuppressWarnings`.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class Foo {

    public Session acquireSession() {
        // All DB opening, connection etc. removed,
        // since the problem is in compilation, not at runtime.
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") /* <----- */

    public List<Foo> activeObjects() {
        Session s = acquireSession();
        Query   q = s.createQuery("from foo where active");
        return (List<Foo>) q.list();
    }
}
```

**I would like to get rid of that `SuppressWarnings`**. But if I do, I get the warning

```
Warning: Unchecked cast from List to List<Foo>
```

(I can ignore it, but I'd like to not get it in the first place), and if I remove the  generic to conform to `.list()` return type, I get the warning

```
Warning: List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E>
should be parameterized.
```

I noticed that `org.hibernate.mapping` *does* declare a `List`; but it is a different type altogether - `Query` returns a `java.util.List`, as a raw type. I find it odd that a recent Hibernate (4.0.x) would not implement parameterized types, so I suspect that it's me instead doing something wrong.

It looks very much like [Cast Hibernate result to a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864093/cast-hibernate-result-to-a-list-of-objects), but here I have no "hard" errors (the system knows type Foo, and I'm not using a SQLQuery but a straight Query). So no joy.

I have also looked at [Hibernate Class Cast Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754777/hibernate-class-cast-exception) since it looked promising, but then I realized that I do *not* actually get any `Exception`... my problem is just that of a warning - a coding style, if you will.

Documentation on jboss.org, Hibernate manuals and several tutorials do not seem to cover the topic in *such* detail (or I didn't search in the right places?). When they do enter into detail, they use on-the-fly casting - and this on tutorials that weren't on the official jboss.org site, so I'm a bit wary.

The code, once compiled, runs with no *apparent* problem... that I know of... yet; and the results are the expected ones.

So: am I doing this right? Am I missing something obvious? Is there an "official"
or "recommended" *Way To Do It*?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Short answer `@SuppressWarnings` is the right way to go.

Long answer, Hibernate returns a  raw `List` from the `Query.list` method, see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list()). This is not a bug with Hibernate or something the can be solved, the type returned by the query is *not known* at compile time.

Therefore when you write

```
final List<MyObject> list = query.list();
```

You are doing an unsafe cast from `List` to `List<MyObject>` - this cannot be avoided.

There is no way you can safely carry out the cast as the `List` *could* contain anything.

The only way to make the error go away is the even more ugly

```
final List<MyObject> list = new LinkedList<>();
for(final Object o : query.list()) {
    list.add((MyObject)o);
}
```

Comment: I was going to only upvote your answer, hoping a better one would come by. Instead I found out this problem referred to as "ugly cast" by both Bruce Eckel (Thinking in Java) and Robert Sedgewick - *the* Sedgewick. I also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings . Sigh.

Comment: I like your style of using `final`

Comment: If hibernate guys add an argument with type `Class<?>` in `list()`, the problem could be solved. It's a shame to use such an ugly API.

Comment: @BinWang then the unsafe cast would happen somewhere else, it doesn't solve the problem - it just moves it. Needless to say the HQL API has been effectively deprecated for **years** now. JPA has a type safe query API called the [Criteria Query API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider But I cannot find `getResultList` in [hibernate 4.3](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html). How can I find it?

Comment: @BinWang that's the Hibernate Criteria API, not the JPA one. You could start by reading [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Isn't the answer for hibernate to return something with type List<?> or List<Object>? Then at least instead of a compiler warning you'd have to explicitly deal with the fact that you don't know what's in the list getting returned?

Comment: @PeteyPabPro well, I **know** what my query will return some specific type - after all, that's what I'm querying.  So this is a circumstance where I know more than the compiler - casting is the way to indicate that to it.  In any case, as mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913150/what-is-the-proper-way-to-cast-hibernate-query-list-to-listtype/15913247?noredirect=1#comment42510673_15913247) - HQL has been superseded by JPA's typed criteria API; one should really just use that.

Comment: @BoristheSpider agree about JPA, but just for sake of discussion, I still think there is no excuse for a raw type. The argument that you **know** what will happen can be made as an argument against type safety in the first place (I *know* my method will be acting on Strings). This isn't just theoretical. A colleague recently left out a scalar() call in a Query like the one above, and assigned it to a List<Integer>. It wasn't until later in the code that he got an obscure error in an unrelated stack about casting from BigDecimal to Integer.

Comment: @PeteyPabPro While I agree that rawtypes should be avoided, I disagree that the results of a query should be treated as a `List<Object>`. The results should be cast to the expected type and **unit tests** should be added to ensure that the query returns the right results. It is unacceptable to have errors with queries turn up "_later in the code_". Your example is an argument against coding practices that should be anathema in the 21st century. It is, I would suggest, **never** acceptable to have a `List<Object>`.

Comment: You write: *You are doing an unsafe cast from `List<?> to List<MyObject>`*. That's incorrect. The unbounded wildcard type `List<?>` is distinct from the raw type `List`, which is what the `list` method returns. You should have written: *You are doing an unsafe cast from `List` to `List<MyObject>`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider If the unsafe cast happened inside hibernate, while it would still have to be a runtime cast, it could know more for example that inside List<Object>, there are not 5 Foo's and 5 Bar's in the list (since they wrote hibernate). If there was a method query.listOfType<MyObject>(), it could type-check only the first item (if not empty) and know for sure that the rest are all the same. However if the query selects "foo.*, bar.*" the results would be List<Object[]> where listItem[0] is type Foo and listItem[1] is type Bar. This would not be handled by listOfType, which could be ok.

Comment: @CurtisYallop as I said, this answer is about a completely deprecated API. Any argument is moot.

Comment: There is a new type-safe Query class in the latest hibernate! It is org.hibernate.query.Query instead of org.hibernate.Query. See @Taugenichts answer. Or the documentation here: http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Hibernate_5.3_Migration_Guide#Typed_Queries

Comment: @BoristheSpider Please provide a reference to support "the HQL API has been effectively deprecated for years now". Is this based upon your personal experience? HQL appears to be a low-level alternate option which has both advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: I've used C# NHibernate and we preferred Linq over the Criteria API. We used Linq primarily and HQL or SQL if we really needed more power. Linq lambda expressions are translated to SQL by an expression parser. It returns either managed entities or anonymous result-objects. I'm programming Java now and it seems like Criteria is the best, cleanest, recommended API. Although more verbose, Criteria does have some advantages over Linq. It is simple and clear. There are no Linq expression parsing edge-case quirks.

Answer (score 32):

The resolution is to use TypedQuery instead. When creating a query from the EntityManager instead call it like this:

```
TypedQuery<[YourClass]> query = entityManager.createQuery("[your sql]", [YourClass].class);
List<[YourClass]> list = query.getResultList(); //no type warning
```

This also works the same for named queries, native named queries, etc. The corresponding methods have the same names as the ones that would return the vanilla query. Just use this instead of a Query whenever you know the return type.

Comment: As a side note, this does not work for purely native queries that you are creating inline. The returned query is only ever a query, not a typedquery :(

Comment: Now, the error message is gone and the resulting list uses the actual objects instead of the Object object.. great answer!

Comment: This appears to be released in hibernate 5.0. I don't see it in 4.3.11 but the following article refers to 5.3. http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Hibernate_5.3_Migration_Guide#Typed_Queries I also see a Jan 2014 stackoverflow post referring to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21354639/854342.

Comment: It is part of hibernate-jpa-2.0-api. You can use this with hibernate 4.3, as I am currently using it on hibernate 4.3.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question, there is no "proper way" to do that.
Now if it's just the warning that bothers you, the best way to avoid its proliferation is to wrap the `Query.list()` method into a DAO :

```
public class MyDAO {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> List<T> list(Query q){
        return q.list();
    }
}
```

This way you get to use the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` only once.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Anyway, don't forget to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid compiler warning with workarounds like this one:

```
List<?> resultRaw = query.list();
List<MyObj> result = new ArrayList<MyObj>(resultRaw.size());
for (Object o : resultRaw) {
    result.add((MyObj) o);
}
```

But there are some issues with this code:

- created superfluous ArrayList
- unnecessary loop over all elements returned from the query
- longer code.

And the difference is only cosmetic, so using such workarounds is - in my opinion - pointless.

You have to live with these warnings or suppress them.

Comment: I agree with the pointlessness. I'll suppress, even if it goes against my grain. Thanks all the same, and +1.

Comment: >You have to live with these warnings or supress them. It's always better to supress warnings that are wrong, or you can miss right warning in a spam of unsupressed wrong warnings

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
Criteria criteria = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Person.class);
for (final Object o : criteria.list()) {
    list.add((Person) o);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is basically the same 'ugliness' suggested by Boris, with a cast within the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Only way that work for me was with an Iterator.

```
Iterator iterator= query.list().iterator();
Destination dest;
ArrayList<Destination> destinations= new ArrayList<>();
Iterator iterator= query.list().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Object[] tuple= (Object[]) iterator.next();
        dest= new Destination();
        dest.setId((String)tuple[0]);
        dest.setName((String)tuple[1]);
        dest.setLat((String)tuple[2]);
        dest.setLng((String)tuple[3]);
        destinations.add(dest);
    }
```

With other methods that I found, I had cast problems

Comment: What "cast problems"? I have always just casted the list directly, how is the above more concise or safer?

Comment: I can't cast directly. Were cast problems because it couldn't make cast from Object to Destination

Comment: You know Hibernate can build a `Destinstion` for you right? Using the [`select new`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select) syntax. This certainly isn't the right approach.

Comment: I also had same experience. As my query returns different fields from multiple tables which are not connected with each other. So the only way worked for me was this one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You use a ResultTransformer like that:

```
public List<Foo> activeObjects() {
    Session s = acquireSession();
    Query   q = s.createQuery("from foo where active");
    q.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Foo.class));
    return (List<Foo>) q.list();
}
```

Comment: I can't test this now, but... what does this change? `q` is still a `Query` and therefore `q.list()` is still a raw `java.util.List` type. The cast is then still unchecked; having the object type changed *internally* should avail nothing...

Comment: Yes the cast is still unchecked, but with proper naming of your fields, setting a resultTransformer does the job of casting the Objects as your desired POJO. 
See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937131/getting-result-set-into-dto-with-native-sql-query-in-hibernate) and read this [hibernate reference doc on using native queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e17378)

Comment: `from foo where active` is _not_ a native query. So there is no need of a result transformer, as the default mapping will be enough. The question is not about casting the POJO fields, but about casting the result object. A result transformer wouldn't help here.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to use Hibernate Transformers:

```
public class StudentDTO {
private String studentName;
private String courseDescription;

public StudentDTO() { }  
...
}
```

.

```
List resultWithAliasedBean = s.createSQLQuery(
"SELECT st.name as studentName, co.description as courseDescription " +
"FROM Enrolment e " +
"INNER JOIN Student st on e.studentId=st.studentId " +
"INNER JOIN Course co on e.courseCode=co.courseCode")
.setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(StudentDTO.class))
.list();

StudentDTO dto =(StudentDTO) resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);
```

Iterating througth Object[] is redundant and would have some performance penalty.
Detailed information about transofrmers usage you will find here:
[Transformers for HQL and SQL](http://in.relation.to/2006/03/17/hibernate-32-transformers-for-hql-and-sql/)

If you are looking for even more simple solution you can use out-of-the-box-map-transformer:

```
List iter = s.createQuery(
"select e.student.name as studentName," +
"       e.course.description as courseDescription" +
"from   Enrolment as e")
.setResultTransformer( Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP )
.iterate();

String name = (Map)(iter.next()).get("studentName");
```

Comment: The question was not about result transformation. It was about casting of `Query` results - which is still needed in your example. And your example has nothing to do with the original `from foo where active`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution [here](http://learningviacode.blogspot.com.uy/2013/04/sessioncreatesqlquery.html), the key of this issue is the  **addEntity** method

```
public static void testSimpleSQL() {
    final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("select * from ENTITY");
    q.addEntity(Entity.class);
    List<Entity> entities = q.list();
    for (Entity entity : entities) {
        System.out.println(entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just just using **Transformers** It did not work for me I was getting type cast exception.

`sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MYEngityName.class))`
did notwork because I was getting Array of Object in the return list element not the fixed MYEngityName type of list element.

It worked for me when I make following changes When I have added `sqlQuery.addScalar(-)` each selected column and its type and for specific String type column we dont have to map its type. like `addScalar("langCode");`

And I have join MYEngityName with NextEnity we cant just `select *` in the Query  it will give array of Object in the return list.

Below code sample :

```
session = ht.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                String sql = new StringBuffer("Select txnId,nft.mId,count,retryReason,langCode FROM  MYEngityName nft INNER JOIN NextEntity m on nft.mId  =  m.id where nft.txnId < ").append(lastTxnId)
                       .append(StringUtils.isNotBlank(regionalCountryOfService)? " And  m.countryOfService in ( "+ regionalCountryOfService +" )" :"")
                       .append(" order by nft.txnId desc").toString();
                SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
                sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MYEngityName.class));
                sqlQuery.addScalar("txnId",Hibernate.LONG)
                        .addScalar("merchantId",Hibernate.INTEGER)
                        .addScalar("count",Hibernate.BYTE)
                        .addScalar("retryReason")
                        .addScalar("langCode");
                sqlQuery.setMaxResults(maxLimit);
                return sqlQuery.list();
```

It might help some one. in this way work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In a project I'm a consultant I had this issue. See the solution:
First, I created the following method:

```
protected <T> MyTypedQuery<T> createNamedAliasQuery(final String queryName, final Class<T> type) {  
    final Query q = getSafeEntityManager().createNamedQuery(queryName);
    q.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class)
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(type));  
    return new MyTypedQuery<T>(q); 
}
```

Second, I create a MyTypedQuery, which looks like a wrapper, as below:

```
public class MyTypedQuery<R> implements TypedQuery<R> {
    private Query q;
    
    public MyTypedQuery(Query q) {
        this.q = q;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int executeUpdate() {
        return this.q.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public int getFirstResult() {
        return this.q.getFirstResult();
    }

    @Override
    public FlushModeType getFlushMode() {
        return this.q.getFlushMode();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getHints() {
        return this.q.getHints();
    }

    @Override
    public LockModeType getLockMode() {
        return this.q.getLockMode();
    }

    @Override
    public int getMaxResults() {
        return this.q.getMaxResults();
    }

    @Override
    public Parameter<?> getParameter(String arg0) {
        return this.q.getParameter(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public Parameter<?> getParameter(int arg0) {
        return this.q.getParameter(arg0);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> Parameter<T> getParameter(String arg0, Class<T> arg1) {
        return (Parameter<T>) this.q.getParameter(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Parameter<T> getParameter(int arg0, Class<T> arg1) {
        return (Parameter<T>) this.q.getParameter(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T getParameterValue(Parameter<T> arg0) {
        return (T) this.q.getParameterValue(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getParameterValue(String arg0) {
        return this.q.getParameterValue(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getParameterValue(int arg0) {
        return this.q.getParameterValue(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Parameter<?>> getParameters() {
        return this.q.getParameters();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBound(Parameter<?> arg0) {
        return this.q.isBound(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> arg0) {
        return this.q.unwrap(arg0);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<R> getResultList() {
        return (List<R>) this.q.getResultList();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public R getSingleResult() {
        return (R) this.q.getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public TypedQuery<R> setFirstResult(int arg0) {
        this.q.setFirstResult(arg0);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedQuery<R> setFlushMode(FlushModeType arg0) {
        this.q.setFlushMode(arg0);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedQuery<R> setHint(String arg0, Object arg1) {
        this.q.setHint(arg0, arg1);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedQuery<R> setLockMode(LockModeType arg0) {
        this.q.setLockMode(arg0);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedQuery<R> setMaxResults(int arg0) {
        this.q.setMaxResults(arg0);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypedQuery<R> setParameter(Parameter<T> arg0, T arg1) {
        this.q.setParameter(arg0, arg1);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedQuery<R> setParameter(String arg0, Object arg1) {
        this.q.setParameter(arg0, arg1);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedQuery<R> setParameter(int arg0, Object arg1) {
        this.q.setParameter(arg0, arg1);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedQuery<R> setParameter(Parameter<Calendar> arg0, Calendar arg1, TemporalType arg2) {
        this.q.setParameter(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedQuery<R> setParameter(Parameter<Date> arg0, Date arg1, TemporalType arg2) {
        this.q.setParameter(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedQuery<R> setParameter(String arg0, Calendar arg1, TemporalType arg2) {
        this.q.setParameter(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedQuery<R> setParameter(String arg0, Date arg1, TemporalType arg2) {
        this.q.setParameter(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedQuery<R> setParameter(int arg0, Calendar arg1, TemporalType arg2) {
        this.q.setParameter(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedQuery<R> setParameter(int arg0, Date arg1, TemporalType arg2) {
        this.q.setParameter(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Third (and last), the use is straightforward like:

```
final List<Car> list = 
            createNamedAliasQuery("your-named-query", Car.class)
                .setParameter("idCar", idCar)
                .setParameter("idModel", idModel)
                .getResultList();
```

Note that @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") appears once in our MyTypedQuery and not in every single use.

Comment: what issue is this resolving over using the default typedquery? It seems as though this is just a passthrough to the underlying methods of a typedquery.

Comment: Taugenichts it is exactly that. Without that, there were _unsafe cast_ warning through the whole system. Now, in a *unique* place with a single @SuppressWarnings.

Comment: TypedQueries have a type so you won't get a unsafe cast warning.
If you just changed this line:

final Query q = getSafeEntityManager().createNamedQuery(queryName);

to 

final TypedQuery<Car> q = getSafeEntityManager().createNamedQuery(queryName, Car.class);

you could kill your whole wrapper class.

Comment: Yes @Taugenichts, you're right. However, in my answer I am talking about "named alias query", i.e., named query that also uses a ResultTransformer (aliasToBean). The direct way you suggested does work perfectly *only* with named query.

Answer (score 0):

First of you have ensure the naming in HQL.

Use the name of the entity in the HQL query.
If you don't specify any name in the @Entity annotation then the default is your class name.

[image]

For More Information:
https://javabydeveloper.com/org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-querysyntaxexception-entity-table-is-not-mapped/

Answer (score 0):

I use that it work well:

```
private List<VehicleUserResult> createQueryVehiclesBYUser(Integer userId) {
        final Session session= getSession();
        Query consulta= session.createQuery("from VehicleUser where user=:user");
        consulta.setParameter("user",userId);
        return (List<VehicleUserResult>) consulta.getResultList();
    }
```