# How to return specific type instead of List<Object[]> in Hibernate Criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have two classes

```
@Entity
public class user implements Serializable{
...
private Set<article> uploaded = new HashSet<article>();
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy="uploader")
public Set<article> getUploaded() {
return uploaded;
}

@Entity
public class article  implements Serializable{
....
private user uploader;
....
@ManyToOne
public user getUploader() {
    return uploader;
}
```

So there also are two tables in the database: user and article. I try to get data using Criteria:

```
tx = session.beginTransaction();
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(article.class);
...
List<article> list = cr.list();
```

But the returned list is not `List<article>`, it's a `List<Object>` contains ARTICLE and USER, and I don't know how to get the ARTICLE data from the list. if I set FetchType.Lazy, then the returned list will be `List<article>` without USER data, but I also need the USER data...

Answer (score 3):

The Criteria Hibernate class `list()` method return a raw List. So if you try to cast
it you get an unchecked warning.

> But the returned list is not List, it's a List contains ARTICLE and USER

It doesn't contain both article and user, it contains only the type you passed when you create the criteria. In this case:

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(article.class);
```

The list returned will contain article objects.

You can get a list of article in different ways:

The easiest one:

```
//Cast the raw list, but this will give you an unchecked warning
List<article> list = (List<article>) cr.list();
```

Or you can copy the values in another list:

```
List<Object> list = cr.list();
List<article> articles = new ArrayList<article>();

for(Object object : list) {
   if(object instanceof article) {
      articles.add((article) object);
   } 
}
```

Look at this post : [What is the "proper" way to cast Hibernate Query.list() to List<Type>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913150/what-is-the-proper-way-to-cast-hibernate-query-list-to-listtype)

Anyway, class names must start with an uppercase character for java naming conventions. article -> Article, user -> User

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I did some test, it works like this:List<article> articles = new ArrayList<article>();
   for (Object[] object : list) {
    articles.add((article) object[1]);
   }

Answer (score -1):

Use Projection or ResultSetTransformer:

.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(article.class));

it's easy to google.