# How to resolve java.lang.ClassCastException for query.list() in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi Im really new to java  programming.

But im trying to perform select option using Hibernate but im getting a exception

Here is my code.

```
public List<Ticket> getTableData(Ticket parameters, String username, int minCount, int start) throws HibernateException, SQLException, Exception {

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query query;

        query = session.createQuery("FROM Ticket T "
                + "INNER JOIN Systemuser SU ON SU.employee.employeeid = T.employee.employeeid "
                + "INNER JOIN Status S ON S.statusid = T.status.statusid "
                + "WHERE SU.username = :username AND S.isfinalstatus <> :isfinalstatus");
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        query.setParameter("isfinalstatus", MasterDataVarList.AFFINITI_CODE_ISFINALSTATUS);

        query.setMaxResults(minCount);
        query.setFirstResult(start);
        return query.list();
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the COMPLETE exception message and stack trace (format as code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "proper" way to cast Hibernate Query.list() to List<Type>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913150/what-is-the-proper-way-to-cast-hibernate-query-list-to-listtype)

Comment: I only use the JPA interfaces, but I assume this one covers them as well, so try adding `Ticket.class` as the second parameter in `createQuery`. Also I suggest you start the query with `SELECT T FROM Ticket T`, because those joins will confuse the result mapper.