# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast

Tags: spring-mvc

hey Hi so this my service layer code

```
    BillType billType=billTypeList.get(i);
```

This is my dao code:

```
     @Override
        public List<BillType>   getBillTypeList(BillCategory billCategoryId){
            Session session = null;
            List<BillType> billTypeList=null;

            try {
                 session=sessionFactory.openSession();
                String sql = "select * from BILL_TYPE  where BILL_CATEGORY_ID=:billCategoryId";         
                 Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
                 query.setParameter("billCategoryId", billCategoryId);
                 billTypeList= query.list();      

            }
            catch(Exception e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 logger.error("Error in Method getBillType "+e.getMessage());
             }
            finally {
                  if (session != null) {
                    if (session.isOpen())
                      session.close();
                  }
            }
            return billTypeList;
        }
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.mppmcl.nonpower.model.BillType
```

Please tell me what to do. would be of great help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the attributes of BillType?Also there's an error in your code

```
query.setParameter("billCategoryId", billCategoryId);
```

You cant pass an Object as hibernate parameter. This will cause an unmatching type error. Try passing **Integer** values, it will match the ID Type.
Try this

```
query.setParameter("billCategoryId", billCategoryId.getId());
```

To know more about mapping, check this [Java type Mappings](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm)

Comment: Could you edit the answer? It is a little bit unclear to me what is the solution. I would recommend to remove questions and stuff like **EDIT** from your post. It is not really adding anything to the answer.

Comment: billcategory id is of type billcategory which is an object....and i do not really think ur solution will work

Comment: i am receiving the billtypelist from dao. only problem is when i am trying to receive the ith object from the list in service, i am getting an error and i am getting an exception

Answer (score 0):

Just to get rid of this error, by putting `@SuppressWarnings` on your method will do the trick.

But you should see a proper way to handle this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15913247/6572971)